# Rename from 'C:/.../repo/.git/index.lock' to 'C:/.../repo/.git/index' failed al pasar por caja de una branch a otra

Tags: git

Desde hace un suéter muy reciente tengo este error que me impide ir a cualquier parte de mis ramas git:

```
(venv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\data-tools>git checkout change_subscriptions
Rename from 'C:/.../repo/.git/index.lock' to 'C:/.../repo/.git/index' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

Si hago y, me sale el mismo mensaje de error, si hago n se para todo y no puedo ir a la rama tampoco

Answer (score 0):

En https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635429/git-rename-from-index-lock-to-index-failed comentan que es porque hay un proceso que tiene abierto el archivo `.git/index` (en ese caso era un proceso de `ssh-agent`). Matando el proceso que tenga abierto el archivo, debe ser posible entonces realizar el checkout. Y como se sabe qué proceso tiene abierto un archivo? en Güindous? Ni idea.